# How to load additional properties of a record?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In short, I need to load **additional fields** of a record, after it's been selected with the **non-complete set of properties**.

Consider the following query:

```
$quotes = Quote::select(['id', 'probability'])->get();
```

after doing some manipulations with `$quotes` and choosing one of the quotes - `$q`, I need to load it's additional properties. How can this be achieved?

Comment: make again request and get those properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious solution:

```
$quotes = Quote::select(['id', 'probability'])->get();
$chosen_quote = chooseOneQuote($quotes); // Your algorithm that chooses quote
$q = Quote::find($q->id);
```